# No SelectionChanged event triggered in a ComboBox (WinRT with Windows.UI.Interactivity)

Tags: mvvm, binding, combobox, command, winrt-xaml

I am using recently released Windows.UI.Interactivity library to wire some events to MVVM commands in a WinRT app. It works fine for ListView, however no event is fired in a ComboBox. Here's a ComboBox control definition (some properties skipped for clarity):

```
<ComboBox 
    x:Name="collectionMode" 
        Margin="10" 
        SelectedIndex="0">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CollectionModeCommand}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Show collection properties" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Show collection data" />
</ComboBox>
```

The CollectionModeCommand is never triggered (I have a similar wiring in a ListView and it works fine).

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. The problem was with the incorrect binding of the outer control that of course resulted in the CollectionModeCommand not being bound to the ComboBox.